# Hibernate Search initialise index in multi-tenant Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Hibernate and I am adding Hibernate Search to it. The application uses schema-separated multi tenancy with Hibernate, implementing `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`

I want to create the initial search index (or re-index) on application startup, in order to be able to search the existing data.

This is the service that does the indexing:

```java
@Service
public class SearchService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void initializeSearchIndex() {

        try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is I don't know where to invoke this service. Because it works off of an `EntityManager` and not a `DataSource`, it seems tied down to a single tenant (db schema). Is there a way to create the index for the entire database? And if so, where to invoke this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you will need to open a different session (entity manager) for each tenant. You can't use a single, cross-tenant mass indexer since that goes against the very concept of multi-tenancy: strictly separating access to each tenant's data.

I don't know the exact way to do it correctly with Spring boot, but your code will look something like this:

```java
@Service
public class SearchService {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public void initializeSearchIndex() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
        for (String tenantId : getAllTenantIds()) {
            try (Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier(tenantId).openSession()) {
                FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(session);
                fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    List<String> getAllTenantIds() {
         // return all tenant Ids
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just for completeness, I needed `.openSession()` when creating the `Session` object.